# how to change the title of a dislayed MessageBox?

Tags: messagebox, msgbox

i use the win api MessageBoxIndirectW to create a new msgbox and i use the api SetTimer to auto-close the msgbox.

now i want to display the time left at the msgbox title every second before auto-close.

i guess there have to be a timer started and running before the msgbox will be created that checks periodically for the msgbox and changes the title.

does someone know how the title of a displayed msgbox can be changed?
maybe with the api SendDlgItemMessageW?

Answer (score 0):

using the api SetWindowTextW inside the timer callback event can be used to change the title of the msgbox!